# Custom function on angular $resource giving error "is not a function"

Tags: angularjs

Service

```
sampleApp.factory('Order', function ($resource, $cacheFactory) {
  return $resource('http://example.com/api/v1/orders/:id', {id: '@id'}, 
  {
    'query':            {method:'GET', cache: true},
    'get':            {method:'GET'},
    'updateRow':      {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}},
    'deleteRow':      {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}},
    'changeStatus':   {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
  });
});
```

Controller:

```
$scope.updateRow = function(od){
    var order = od;
    order.$updateRow();
}
```

Order.get() and Order.query() works fine. but when i try to call my custom function it is giving error: order.$updateRow is not a function

Can anyone help why is this error?

Comment: my bet is that od is the resource creator and not the new Order()??

Comment: that's true, what's od there?

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
$scope.updateRow = function(od){
    Order.updateRow({id: od});
}
```